# Disabling journaling for read-only ext4 fs

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, journaling

If journaling is disabled for a read-only ext4 fs can there be any possible side effects?

I see an opportunity of saving precious storage quota by doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes as per https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot#Preconditions

> You can use a filesystem without a journal for /, because you don't write there and you don't need the journal.

Comment: `can there be any possible side effects?` -> `The answer is Yes` ? Really "yes" or may be "no"?